# Image doesn't load on frontend in mern stack

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, frontend

All content from Mongodb is fetch on frontend react card except the image. the candidate data is store on Mongodb and I fetch it on frontend as card body but the image is not loading.

**server.js file fetch data code**

```
app.get('/api/candidates', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const candidates = await Candidate.find();
    res.json(candidates);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Failed to fetch candidates' });
  }
});
```

**candidatecard.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import './CandidateCard.css';

const CandidateCard = ({ candidateName, partyName, imageURL }) => {
  return (
    <div className="candidate-card">
      <img src={imageURL} alt={candidateName} />
      <h2>{candidateName}</h2>
      <h2>{partyName}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CandidateCard;
```

**candidatelist.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import CandidateCard from './CandidateCard';
import './candidate.css';
const CandidateList = () => {
  const [candidates, setCandidates] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/candidates');
      setCandidates(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="candidate-list">
      {candidates.map(candidate => (
        <CandidateCard
          key={candidate._id}
          candidateName={candidate.candidate_name}
          partyName={candidate.party_name}
          imageURL={candidate.imageURL}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default CandidateList;
```

I also wrote some CSS file.
This is how the frontend output look like.

[image: output]

Comment: Seems like the image url isn't correct. What does the image url look like?

Comment: at frontend when post request made for add data on mongodb i make UI as choosefile for image

Comment: yeah in mongodb imageurl field is empty do you know how to do it right

Comment: That depends on how you save the data in mongodb. Please edit your question and add the code for adding the data to mongo.

Comment: is  i have to convert jpeg file to base64Image format and then save it